# How to solve time dependent coupled differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve time dependent coupled differential equations with know initial conditions. I am just a beginner in terms of coding so would really appreciate if someone can give me an example of this kind. Thanks a lot!

Here are the equations:

```
dn = 5.5

A = 10      

s = 1/Sqrt[2]

k1 = A*exp[-(r^2)/(2*s^2)]

kn = 1

EQ1 = D[u[r, t], t] == 
  dn*D[u[r, t], r, r] + (dn/r)*D[u[r, t], r] + k1*y[r, t] + 
   kn*u[r, t]*y[r, t] - kn*u[r, t]

EQ2 = D[y[r, t], {t, 1}] == 
  kn*u[r, t]*y[r, t] - k1*y[r, t] + kn*u[r, t]
```

Initial Condition: `u[r, 0] == 0, y[r, 0] == 0.1`

t goes from $0$ to $100$

Comment: First -- format your code properly (you can find more info in the help centre); Second -- Read about `DSolve` and `NDSolve`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. Here its considered helpful to share your code in a well [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing.
Not bothering reading the documentation is not a good excuse. As suggested by @Sektor please read the help for [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) and then [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) accordingly.

Comment: See [`FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming#1433571051`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html#1433571051)

Answer (score 1):

This system of equations is missing boundary conditions for `u` in `r`.  Here, let us assume `u[0.01, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0` with `r` in the range `{r, 0.01, 1}` to avoid the singularity at `r == 0`.  Also, it is necessary to correct the typo in `k1`: Replace `exp` by `Exp`.  Then,

```
{su, sy} = NDSolveValue[{EQ1, EQ2, u[r, 0] == 0, y[r, 0] == 0.1, 
     u[0.01, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0}, {u, y}, {r, 0.01, 1}, {t, 0, 100}];
Plot3D[su[r, t], {r, 0.01, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, t, u}]
Plot3D[sy[r, t], {r, 0.01, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {r, t, y}]
```

yields

[image]

[image]

Both `u` and `y` are nearly zero for larger values of `t` than those shown in the plots.

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs! I really appreciate it.